# Downgrade AzureRM PowerShell Module

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

Is there a way to downgrade AzureRM PowerShell to older version? I just installed 6.0.1 and realized that it didn't support a few parameters. Is there a quick way to downgrade without using `Uninstall-Module`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there seems no direct downgrade operation according to [PowerShell Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/powershellget/?view=powershell-6).

You can install different versions of AzureRM modules. But only one version can be loaded.

You can `Install-Module -Name AzureRM -RequiredVersion xxx` or `Update-Module -Name AzureRM -RequiredVersion xxx`.

Then open a new powershell window to `Import-Module -Name AzureRM -RequiredVersion xxx`.

Answer (score 1):

You can uninstall the Version and then install your require (working) one:

```
Uninstall-Module -Name AzureRM
Install-Module -Name AzureRM -RequiredVersion 5.7.0
```

Rebooted the machine and TFS indicates the required Version as capability.